# error: cannot find symbol ...String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.DEFAULT);

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java code [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

I have this line

```
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

when I try to run the code I have this error, pointing to this line

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable DEFAULT
  location: class Base64
1 error
```

at the beginning of the code I am importing this:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class HelloWorld{

... bla bla bla
```

what should I import, so I can run this code?

Comment: `Base64.DEFAULT` is from Android, not the `java.util.Base64` class. I suspect you want `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array)`

Comment: Brilliant! Please make this an answer, so I can accept!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Base64.DEFAULT` is from Android, not the `java.util.Base64`. (If you look at the docs for `java.util.Base64`, you'll see it really doesn't have a `DEFAULT` member - you should always be careful about contextual things like this when copying code from elsewhere.

I believe all you need to use `java.util.Base64` is

```java
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array);
```